# Systemd python service buffers journalctl output even with -u

Tags: linux, python, systemd, journald

I have a simple user systemd service configured like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=Bot
AssertPathExists=/home/mikel/discord-bot/

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/mikel/discord-bot/
ExecStart=/home/mikel/anaconda3/bin/python -u bot.py parameters.json
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Essentially, all the service does is run a python script.

However, when I look at the `journalctl` for the service, I see that instead of logs appearing as things happen in the script, it is all flushed at once when the service is stopped (with the same timestamp for every line).

This suggests that some buffer is occuring somewhere that is preventing it from being written to journalctl immediately. However, even when I turn off Python's internal buffer with `-u`, the problem still occurs.

One solution I have found is to wrap it in the `unbuffer` command from the `expect` package, like so:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/unbuffer /home/mikel/anaconda3/bin/python -u bot.py parameters.json
```

However, while this works, it means that journalctl shows "unbuffer[PID]" instead of "python[PID]", and I want a solution that doesn't involve installing external packages for what seems like a simple task.

Is there some other way to remove these buffers so that the output is flushed to journalctl as it comes from python?

Comment: Can you give more details on what bot.py is doing? Is it calling external programs? That could explain why the output is unbuffered on those and why `unbuffer` would fix it...

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you want... But look at [`SyslogIdentifier=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#SyslogIdentifier=) config in systemd. You could use something like `SyslogIdentifier=discord-bot` to actually log your messages as `discord-bot[PID]` which is even better than `python`...

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger As far as I know it is not calling any external programs. At the very least, I know that all the stdout comes from the python process. SyslogIdentifier looks like a decent improvement, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Through your experiment with `unbuffer`, you have established that the buffering is happening in the command you are running, not in `systemd`.

So the buffering is happening in the `python` code you are wrote. To solve that, you need to review the code you wrote or post the code here with a question.

Comment: What should I look out for within the python code? The things that are getting buffered are simple print statements, for example.

Comment: @mxbi There is [already a Q&A on python output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering).

Comment: Mark's answer is a bit obtuse, but it's correct.  At least when run from systemd, Python's buffered output means that it won't write, even if you use systemd's `StardardOutput=file:/some/path` -- that gets buffered too.  All you can do is un-buffer with python's `-u` switch. 

Here's some [python code](https://gist.github.com/sinewalker/6ce06e49afad9e010228b4674e57f715), and a [unit file](https://gist.github.com/sinewalker/4e3d228d6d2124a8bdcec4cf9cb4fffa). Try swapping the different `ExecStart`s and commenting out `StandardOutput` to experiment. It's not the journal buffering, it's Python.

Comment: fyi, when I run `ticktock.py` like this: `./ticktock.py > /tmp/ticktock.log` then that log is also buffered and not updated until the script ends