# Systemd python script won't log (buffer cause)?

Tags: logging, scripting, python, systemd, raspbian

Although the problem [exposed here](https://serverfault.com/questions/909192/systemd-python-service-buffers-journalctl-output-even-with-u) seems very similar, none of the solutions provided work. Context :

- Raspberry Pi Zero W, Raspbian Lite (2020-08-20)
- I want to register a python3 script as a service, to run in background

I wanted to make it go with systemd, which worked with following configuration :

`application.service` lies in `/etc/systemd/system/application.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=application
After=multi-user.target


[Service]
User=custom_user
Type=idle
TimeoutSec=0
PIDFile=/run/application.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /path/to/application.py >> /path/to/log.log 2>&1
KillMode=control-group
Environment="PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"

Restart=always
RestartSec=3s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service correctly loads at startup, on expected segments (related to `Wants` and `WantedBy` sections). **But it won't log anything in log file I provided**. You notice `Environment` entry to force `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` and same thing with the `-u` argument passed on Python executable call. This has no effect at all.

If I launch exactly the same exec line on a CLI, the script runs AND logs. Through the service definition, no log at all.

Sidenotes :

- If i check `journalctl` output, I find my log lines
- `logrotate` and `log2ram` are set up on the log file/directory

I ended up with adding my command line in `/etc/rc.local` followed by an ampersand. This is not a go according to me as I would like to register this service in the best way possible regarding the system it's running on.

Thanks for your replies and enlightments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to use shell redirections in this manner. It doesn't work because systemd is not a shell. Rather, specify [`StandardOutput=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) and [`StandardError=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardError=) explicitly if you want them directed to somewhere other than the journal.